# Diactrical marks not taking the same font-weight as the letters

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having an issue with numerous fonts that I was hoping can be solved in some way. I created a website for a client and the content is written in Faroese, however for some reason when I use a font-weight of 100 for example, the diactrical marks (the weird things above the letters) remain a higher font-weight.

You can see what i mean in the following links - scroll down to the purple call to action area; http://op.n8geeks.com/

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS3vn.jpg

Screenshot was taken on a Mac OSX computer on the latest version of Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see what you are talking about... It seems to be rendered pretty well for me... Any clue, specific browser or something else ? Can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: It's good here (Chrome). Can you provide us a screenshot?

Comment: Tested in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. Works only in Chrome. Others rendering as the problem stated. Besides, has certain cross browser design issues as well. The menu bar gets displaced after resizing the window in chrome.

Comment: Add screenshots. Specify OS. Specify Graphics Drivers.

Comment: Added a screenshot. Mac OSX, Firefox - not sure about graphics drivers.

Comment: for one thing... my Firefox DevTools console shows this:  `downloadable font: OS/2: bad weight: 250 (font-family: "Roboto" style:normal weight:100 stretch:normal src index:2) source: http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/2tsd397wLxj96qwHyNIkxPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2`